# Data from MongoDB is loaded after directive call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an little invoice demo app that I'm building using Angular. Data is stored in a MongoDB and is called to in a controller names appropriately `invoiceCtrl`. The controller looks like this:

```
invCon.controller( 'invoiceCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
        //Ajax call to retrieve items from db
        this.items = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/author'
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('Succesful Response');
            return response.data[0].items;
        }, function errorCallback(response){
            console.log('Error Response');
            console.log(response);
        });
```

The problem I'm having is that by the time the ajax request to retrieve this data has finished the view has already rendered the model and nothing is loaded, that is to say the directive is called and the template is displayed for the data even exists. I thought the way two way data binding worked was that when the model was updated the view would be to? Have I missed something in the way that Angular does it's two way data binding?

Some of the posts I've reasearched seem to recommend using a factory to retrieve this data? Is this something I should be looking into? I'm fairly new to angular so any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:

Here are the directives:

```
(function(){

    var invDir = angular.module('invoice-directives', []);

    invDir.directive('envoyInvoice', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/invoice.html'
        };
    });

    invDir.directive('invoiceLogo', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/parts/invoice-logo.html'
        };
    });

    invDir.directive('invoiceMeta', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/parts/invoice-meta.html'
        };
    });

    invDir.directive('invoiceJob', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/parts/invoice-job.html'
        };
    });

    invDir.directive('invoiceTable', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/parts/invoice-table.html'
        };
    });

    invDir.directive('invoiceSummary', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/invoice/parts/invoice-summary.html'
        };
    });


})();
```

Comment: Please provide your directive code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return the data in success handler. Instead you store it inside your scope variable. For that, First inject `$scope` to your controller.

```
invCon.controller( 'invoiceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        //Ajax call to retrieve items from db
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/author'
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('Succesful Response');
            $scope.items = response.data[0].items;
        }, function errorCallback(response){
            console.log('Error Response');
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Now you can use `items` in your view html. Since angular supports two way binding, The view will be automatically updated, as soon as `$scope.items` is updated.

Comment: Okay so this worked by using $scope. Thanks, I think I need to do some more research about $scopes. 

Much appreciated.